# How to open a local html file in Windows 8.1 mobile app

Tags: windows-phone-8

We are building a **Windows 8.1 mobile app**. We are trying to open a **local html file** in the browser programmatically but do not know how to achieve this functionality. Please let us know how we can implement the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can display web content using the WebBrowser control for Windows Phone 8
this Link may use for You

[WebBrowser control for WP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff431811(v=vs.105).aspx)